# Infinite Horizontal Scroll in Android ViewGroups

Tags: android, scroll, launcher, infinite

I was trying to implement a "wrap-around" or an "infinite scroll" in the base Android Launcher, along the lines of the TouchWiz launcher, for instance.

Kinda stuck with the implementation. Any pointers?